# MySQL workbench sometimes show square boxes for non-english characters

Tags: mysql-workbench

I had read up on different languages having different byte sizes(e.g. English and Japanese),and therefore the configurations(collation,character set) have to be set accordingly.But 1 thing I realized was that sometimes when I run MySQL workbench it shows the proper characters,and at other times show square boxes instead.Is it a bug in MySQL workbench,or is it something else that I had not done properly?Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: did you solve it bro?

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this when I freshly installed my mysql workbench, so what I did was I just reopened it and was fixed. I think it's because the application was not installed properly.